# Using variable from client API callback in node backend

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I make a request on client side using the code below

> public/foo.js

```
function bar() {
  fetch('https://api.github.com/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

how can I send the `data` variable to node backend?

> /app.js

```
app.get("/", cors(), (request, response) => {
  response.render('index.html');
})
```

Comment: Doesn't  ``data`` come from your server-side's ``response``? Sorry but I'm not sure what you are trying to do?

Comment: No the API request is made on client-side as explained, I would like to access this variable on node to perform sensitive data handling, the devtool always keep payload in plain text

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you are trying to fetch data from the URL that is not handled by your server-side on your client-side and send that data back to your own server-side.

On your server-side, create a new POST method:

```
app.post("/example", cors(), (request, response) => {
  let body = request.body;
  response.json(body);
})
```

On your client-side, send a new POST request:

```
function postExample(data) {
  return fetch(`http://localhost:YOURPORT/example`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
}
```

Replace `YOURPORT` with your server's port. And make a call to the `postExample`:

```
function bar() {
  fetch('https://api.github.com/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      postExample(data).then(res => res.json())
                       .then(console.log(res));
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```